# How to split string and make it printed in different line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this link:

```
http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/14769-free_studio
```

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/14769-free_studio"
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for b in soup.select("h1#articleTitle"):
    a = b.contents[0].strip()
    print "app_name: "+a
```

The output is:

```
app_name: Free Studio 2013 v6.1.12.925
```

But I need the output to be like this:

```
app_name: Free Studio 2013
version: v6.1.12.925
```

How can I possibly do that?

Comment: Please add python tag

Comment: What do you mean? @KDawG

Comment: apart from the python-2.7 and beatifulsoup tags add a python tag to make it view-able to a bigger audience

Comment: Thanks..I will add the tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some idea for you:

```
text = 'app_name: Free Studio 2013 v6.1.12.925'
ver_pos = text.find(' v') #It is token for get version
print '%s \nversion: %s' % (text[:ver_pos], text[ver_pos:])
```

Result:

```
app_name: Free Studio 2013 
version:  v6.1.12.925
```

Comment: what about this link http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/25149-nero_video and http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/28792-divx? @Michael Kazarian

Comment: It not general case for random name. I would not try get version if it not in page in clear view.

Comment: As variant I would try system for recognize most name patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the results of the split, and then use `"\n".join(your_var)` to glue the contents together by newline.

Then you could simply print that result in the shape you want.

Comment: I think, author want get version from string.